# Angular material MDC migration to 15 getWorkspaceConfigGracefully is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have migrated angular version from 14 to 15 including material. I'm trying to migrate material UI components using

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

when I entered the command I'm getting following error

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCCub.png)

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
? Limit the migration to a specific directory? (Enter the relative path such as 'src/app/shared' or leave blank for all directories)
? What components do you want to migrate? Button, Card, Checkbox, Chips, Dialog, Form Field, Input, Select, Autocomplete, List, Menu, Paginator, Progress Bar, Progress
Spinner, Radio, Slide Toggle, Slider, Snack Bar, Table, Tabs, Tooltip
(0 , import_schematics4.getWorkspaceConfigGracefully) is not a function
```

I have taken reference from here https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration

I ran migration command  using "ng update" which throwing the error